# jQuery get width of div on resize

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get the width of a div on resize and show it in the console like this..

```js
function matchHeight() {
    var newHeight = jQuery("#container").height(); //where #grownDiv is what's growing
 console.log(newHeight);
}


jQuery(window).on('resize', function(){
matchHeight();
});
```

```css
#container{
  background:tan;
  width:100%;
  height:500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
Container Content
</div>
```

It is not refreshing the value, where am I going wrong?

Comment: What do you do to trigger the 'resize' event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably because you want to grab the width, and instead you're grabbing the height... which doesn't change on resize.

```
function matchWidth() {
    var newWidth = jQuery("#container").width(); //where #grownDiv is what's growing
    console.log(newWidth);
}


jQuery(window).on('resize', function(){
    matchWidth();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You want the width, but you're calling `.height()`. Try `var newWidth= jQuery("#container").width();`